# Calculating overlap between groups

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot

I have a table with two columns of interest, `item_id` and `bucket_id`.  There are a fixed number of values for `bucket_id` and I'm okay with listing them out if I need to.

Each `item_id` can appear multiple times, but each occurrence will have a separate `bucket_id` value.  For example, the `item_id` of `123` can appear twice in the table, once under `bucket_id` of `A`, once under `B`.

My goal is to determine how much overlap exists between each pair of `bucket_id` values and display it as an N-by-N matrix.

For example, consider the following small example table:

```
item_id     bucket_id
=========   ===========
111         A
111         B
111         C

222         B
222         D

333         A
333         C

444         C
```

So for this dataset, buckets `A` and `B` have one `item_id` in common, buckets `C` and `D` have no items in common, etc.

I would like to get the above table formatted into something like the following:

```
        A       B       C       D
===================================
A       2       1       2       0
B       1       2       1       1
C       2       1       3       0
D       0       1       0       1
```

In the above table, the intersect of a row and column tells you how many records exist in both `bucket_id` values.  For example, where the `A` row intersects the `C` column we have a `2`, because there are 2 records that exist in both `bucket_id` A and C.  Because the intersection of X and Y is the same as the intersection of Y and X, the above table is mirrored across the diagonal.

I imagine the query involves a `PIVOT`, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get it working.

Comment: What does the last table represent (e.g. what does a value of 2 for row A column C represent)?

Comment: @John - I added a bit more explanation just below the table.

Comment: It's kind of metric. but connfusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple PIVOT:

```
SELECT t1.bucket_id,
       SUM( CASE WHEN t2.bucket_id = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS A,
       SUM( CASE WHEN t2.bucket_id = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS B,
       SUM( CASE WHEN t2.bucket_id = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS C,
       SUM( CASE WHEN t2.bucket_id = 'D' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS D
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table1 t2 ON t1.item_id = t2.item_id
GROUP BY t1.bucket_id
ORDER BY 1
;
```

or you can use Oracle PIVOT clause (works on 11.2 and above):

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT t1.bucket_id AS Y_bid,
          t2.bucket_id AS x_bid
   FROM table1 t1
   JOIN table1 t2 ON t1.item_id = t2.item_id
)
PIVOT (
  count(*) FOR x_bid in ('A','B','C','D')
)
ORDER BY 1
;
```

Examples: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/39d30/7

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should get you the data you need.  Pivoting the table could then be done programmatically (or in Excel, etc.).

```
-- This gets the distinct pairs of buckets
select distinct
    a.name,
    b.name
from
    bucket a
    join bucket b
where
    a.name < b.name
order by
    a.name,
    b.name

+ --------- + --------- +
| name      | name      |
+ --------- + --------- +
| A         | B         |
| A         | C         |
| A         | D         |
| B         | C         |
| B         | D         |
| C         | D         |
+ --------- + --------- +
6 rows

-- This gets the distinct pairs of buckets with the counts you are looking for
select distinct
    a.name,
    b.name,
    count(distinct bi.item_id)
from
    bucket a
    join bucket b
    left outer join bucket_item ai on ai.bucket_name = a.name
    left outer join bucket_item bi on bi.bucket_name = b.name and ai.item_id = bi.item_id
where
    a.name < b.name
group by
    a.name,
    b.name
order by
    a.name,
    b.name

+ --------- + --------- + ------------------------------- +
| name      | name      | count(distinct bi.item_id)      |
+ --------- + --------- + ------------------------------- +
| A         | B         | 2                               |
| A         | C         | 1                               |
| A         | D         | 0                               |
| B         | C         | 2                               |
| B         | D         | 0                               |
| C         | D         | 0                               |
+ --------- + --------- + ------------------------------- +
6 rows
```

Here's the entire example with the DDL and inserts to set it up (this is in mysql but the same ideas apply elsewhere):

```
use example;

drop table if exists bucket;

drop table if exists item;

drop table bucket_item;

create table bucket (
    name varchar(1)
);

create table item(
    id int
);

create table bucket_item(
    bucket_name varchar(1) references bucket(name),
    item_id int references item(id)
);

insert into bucket values ('A');
insert into bucket values ('B');
insert into bucket values ('C');
insert into bucket values ('D');

insert into item values (111);
insert into item values (222);
insert into item values (333);
insert into item values (444);
insert into item values (555);

insert into bucket_item values ('A',111);
insert into bucket_item values ('A',222);
insert into bucket_item values ('A',333);
insert into bucket_item values ('B',222);
insert into bucket_item values ('B',333);
insert into bucket_item values ('B',444);
insert into bucket_item values ('C',333);
insert into bucket_item values ('C',444);
insert into bucket_item values ('D',555);


-- query to get distinct pairs of buckets
select distinct
    a.name,
    b.name
from
    bucket a
    join bucket b
where
    a.name < b.name
order by
    a.name,
    b.name
;

select distinct
    a.name,
    b.name,
    count(distinct bi.item_id)
from
    bucket a
    join bucket b
    left outer join bucket_item ai on ai.bucket_name = a.name
    left outer join bucket_item bi on bi.bucket_name = b.name and ai.item_id = bi.item_id
where
    a.name < b.name
group by
    a.name,
    b.name
order by
    a.name,
    b.name
;
```